# For Penicillin Binding proteins, why is the Enzyme-peptide complex less stable than an enzyme-β-lactam complex?

Tags: reference-request, medicinal-chemistry

I'm trying to figure this out. I cannot find any publications that go into good detail about the chemistry of PBP inhibition by β-lactam antibiotics.

PBPs cross-link adjacent pentapeptides to form peptidoglycan. My understanding is that in most bacteria, this pentapeptide has a terminal D-Ala-D-Ala dipeptide. The enzyme removes the terminal D-Ala and forms a D-Ala-Enzyme complex, where the enzyme is linked to the rest of the peptide via ester bond to the D-Ala.

However, when PBPs bind to β-lactams, they also for a β-lactam-ester-enzyme complex. However, this complex is more stable so the β-lactam remains in the active site. Why? What's different about the β-lactam ester? Or is it perhaps steric bulk that prevents the enzyme from being freed?

Any good publications are also very welcome.